# Kubernetes Ingress | could not resolve hostname

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I created a ingress cluster and a ingress service first and then to route a request to point to NodePort-serviceA (resources-service) and NodePort-serviceB (staffing-service) in a k8s-cluster, an ingress file (by name of staffing-ingress.yaml) is applied mentioned below.

Resources-service and Staffing-service can communicate with each other from inside the container and while hitting a curl command “curl –v http://staffing-service:8080/swagger/index.html” from resources container returns accurate result with HTTP 200 and vice versa. However if the incomplete URL is hit like this http://staffing-service:8080/, it throws a 404 error.

I have a doubt the way paths routing is done in the staffing-ingress.yaml file below. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Here are the details**

Accessing the services (staffing or resources) using nginx load balancer IP does not return the results and throw 404 error.

```
Curl –v http:// a5b9f45d4119a11eabbd90a9c35f3125-1159448980.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:80/api/resources throws the below error
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to a5b9f45d4119a11eabbd90a9c35f3125-1159448980.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com (3.134.165.38) port 80 (#0)

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
< X-Response-Time-ms: 0
```

**Staffing-Ingress.YAML**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staffing-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/resources
        backend:
          serviceName: resources-service
          servicePort: 8001
      - path: /api/staffing
        backend:
          serviceName: staffing-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

**Expected result**
is that while hitting from ingress using external LB having URI‘/api/resources/’ it should call the api-service http://resources-service:8001/swagger/index.html.

Comment: You are using the wrong URL. I have provided an answer on how you can use the correct URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working properly in term of routing.
You are using the URL wrong.
You have to use this url

`http:// a5b9f45d4119a11eabbd90a9c35f3125-1159448980.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:80/api/resources/swagger/index.html`

You have to append **swagger/index.html** in your url just like you are doing it while accessing it via service.

```
curl –v http://staffing-service:8080/swagger/index.html


curl –v http:// a5b9f45d4119a11eabbd90a9c35f3125-1159448980.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:80/api/resources/swagger/index.html
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, it worked. :) Is there a possibility to do any changes in the configuration file so that call to .../api/recources itself adds suffix .. /swagger/index.html to the end.

Comment: Yes, you can add "rewrite-target" annotation in your Staffing-Ingress.YAML.

Comment: like this:
"ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/resources/swagger/index.html"

Comment: Thanks, Isn't in this case, a request for /api/staffing will also be redirected to /api/resources/swagger/index.html. can we have multiple redirects

Comment: You can remove the /api/staffing config from this one, and create a new Ingress resource with /api/staffing without the "rewrite-target" annotation

Comment: nice!, got it. For troubleshooting, are there any logs that show the complete URI generated as per the path/paths configure in your Ingress file.

Answer (score 0):

Ingress does not remove the context path!

So your call to `www.xxx.yyy/api/resources/` before Ingress is not equal to `www.xxx.yyy/` after ingress. The idea is that your backing service will also require to have the same context path.

The thing that you need to do is to add a context path to both services:

```
resources-service: www.xxx.yyy/api/resources/swagger/index.html
staffing-service: www.xxx.yyy/api/staffing/swagger/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have not tested yet but I believe you are correct and this should work.